# Django Tastypie, do stuff after creating a user

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'd like to add some values to my user Profile model after I create (POST) a user with Tastypie.

This is just one scenario, I have other instances where I might want to alter the data PRE or POST save in my tastypie resource.  Is this possible or how would I go about achieving this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Will a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save) do what you want?

Comment: Rather post_save, and because auth user profiles usually use the same signal to create profile for newly created user, you may not actually solve OP's problem that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can also override obj_create on your Tastypie user resource.
This will give you access to the bundle where the user object is and you can put more values to the fields there.
Here's an example:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        username = bundle.data['username']
        password = bundle.data['password']
        bundle.obj = User.objects.create_user(username,password)
        # add more stuff here

        bundle.obj.save()
        return bundle
```